# Oracle: Selecting Sums From Columns as both: YTD (Year to Date), Fiscal YTD

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sum, querying

I'm relatively new to Oracle and have been spending the better part of the day trying to write a query to return YTD and Fiscal YTD totals on a column.

A simplified version of the table with only relevant columns looks something like:

```
INVOICE_NUM  |  INVOICE_DATE  |  ORDER_CODE  |  ORDER_COST
    509         '14-FEB-20'      'ORD001'         34.99
    509         '14-FEB-20'      'ORD002'         14.99
    509         '14-FEB-20'      'ORD003'         59.99
    428         '16-JAN-20'      'ORD001'         34.99
    428         '16-JAN-20'      'ORD002'         14.99
    306         '14-DEC-19'      'ORD001'         34.99
    306         '14-DEC-19'      'ORD002'         14.99
    201         '15-NOV-19'      'ORD001'         34.99
    108         '16-OCT-19'      'ORD001'         34.99
```

Where an Order is a recurring charge that reappears in each invoice based on logic elsewhere. What I need to return is the total cost for a given invoice along with the YTD total for the order code as well as the Fiscal YTD (starting Nov 1st) for each order code. For this sample set, my query should return for invoice 509:

```
ORDER_CODE  |  CURRENT_INVOICE_TOTAL  |  YTD_TOTAL  |  FISCAL_YTD_TOTAL
 'ORD001'             34.99                69.69           139.96
 'ORD002'             14.99                29.98            44.97
 'ORD003'             59.99                59.99            59.99
```

As of now, all I have is:

```
SELECT 
    order_code
    SUM(order_cost)
FROM 
    table_name
WHERE 
    invoice_num = :invoice_num
GROUP BY
    order_code
```

My attempts at YTD have failed thus far *but* the dev environment also has very poor data so there's no real way to test it. As of now, I'm planning to create a temp table with fake data to try to figure this out.

**EDIT for clarity**: The query should return the YTD totals for the given invoice date. For example, were I to query, in 2020, an invoice from May 2018, it should return the YTD totals for each order_code contained within that invoice from Jan 2018 - May 2018

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Conditional Aggregation` such as

```
SELECT order_code, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN invoice_num = :invoice_num then order_cost END ) AS current_invoice_total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN to_char(sysdate,'yyyy') = to_char(invoice_date,'yyyy') then
                  order_cost
              END ) AS ytd_total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN invoice_date 
             BETWEEN to_date(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy')-1||'-11-01','yyyy-mm-dd')
                 AND to_date(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy')||'-10-31'  ,'yyyy-mm-dd')
             THEN
                  order_cost
              END ) AS fiscal_ytd_total              
  FROM t
 GROUP BY order_code
 ORDER BY order_code
```

Depending on the **Edit** in the Question, Use a `Cross Join` Among your table and derived `invoice_date` from `:invoice_num` bind variable :

```
SELECT t.order_code, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN invoice_num = :invoice_num THEN order_cost END ) 
             AS current_invoice_total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN invoice_date 
             BETWEEN TRUNC(invoice_date2,'yyyy')
                 AND invoice_date2
                THEN
                     order_cost
                END ) AS ytd_total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN invoice_date 
             BETWEEN to_date(to_char(invoice_date2,'yyyy')-1||'-11-01','yyyy-mm-dd')
                 AND invoice_date2
                THEN
                     order_cost
                END ) AS fiscal_ytd_total           
  FROM t
 CROSS JOIN ( SELECT MAX(invoice_date) AS invoice_date2 
                FROM t 
               WHERE invoice_num = :invoice_num ) t2
 GROUP BY order_code
 ORDER BY order_code
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bd6017839b29b3fa1ea6dabdb854c475)</kbd>

Comment: This is actually quite close to what I had (regarding YTD as I hadn't ventured into Fiscal YTD yet). This may have been something I failed to clarify but I'm not guaranteed to run the query within the same timeframe as the invoice_date. It looks like the use of `sysdate` would return an incorrect YTD total if I were to select an invoice_num that occurred in, say, 2018. Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: just replace sysdate (current date) with a date value literal from 2018 say date'2018-04-05', then you'd get summed cost for the range date'2017-11-01' and date'2018-10-31' as fiscal_ytd, and for the range date'2018-01-01' and date'2018-10-31' as ytd_total, e.g you can dynamically select from the current and/or the previous years @MichaelCole

Comment: This select statement will be executed as a hibernate query that's only given the invoice_num so, is there a way to, first, get the invoice_date of that particular invoice and then use that particular date rather than sysdate or a manually input date?

Comment: Alternatively, I could have a separate query grab the invoice_date and then pass that date into the query you provided. Just wanted to see if there's a way to remove the middle man here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `conditional aggregation` as following:

```
Select order_code, 
       order_cost as CURRENT_INVOICE_TOTAL,
       Sum(case when invoice_date >= trunc(sysdate,'YEAR') then order_cost end) as YTD_TOTAL,
       Sum(case when invoice_date < add_months(trunc(sysdate,'YEAR'), 10) order_cost) as FISCAL_YTD_TOTAL
  From table_name
 Where invoice_num = :invoice_num
   And invoice_date >= add_months(trunc(sysdate,'YEAR'), -2)
   And invoice_date < add_months(trunc(sysdate,'YEAR'), 12)
Group by order_code, order_cost
```

This solution will use indexes on the `invoice_date` if there is any.

Cheers!!

Comment: This is actually quite close to what I had (regarding YTD as I hadn't ventured into Fiscal YTD yet). This may have been something I failed to clarify but I'm not guaranteed to run the query within the same timeframe as the invoice_date. It looks like the use of `sysdate` would return an incorrect YTD total if I were to select an invoice_num that occurred in, say, 2018. Thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your fiscal year starts in November.  This makes the aggregation a big tricky, particularly a version that will work in both October *and* November.

However, the fiscal year can be calculated by adding two months onto the date and extracting the year.  If we take this approach, then one method is:

```
select order_code,
       max(order_cost) keep (dense_rank first order by invoice_date desc) as current_invoice_total,
       sum(case when trunc(invoice_date, 'YEAR') = trunc(sysdate, 'YEAR')
                then order_cost
           end) as YTD,
       sum(case when trunc(invoice_date + interval '2' month, 'YEAR') = trunc(sysdate + interval '2' month, 'YEAR') 
                then order_cost
           end) as Fiscal_YTD
from t
where trunc(invoice_date, 'YEAR') = trunc(sysdate, 'YEAR') or 
      trunc(invoice_date + interval '2' month, 'YEAR') = trunc(sysdate + interval '2' month, 'YEAR')
group by order_code;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5c3315ccff6c12d88bae11c3a942e68c) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: This is actually quite close to what I had (regarding YTD as I hadn't ventured into Fiscal YTD yet). This may have been something I failed to clarify but I'm not guaranteed to run the query within the same timeframe as the invoice_date. It looks like the use of `sysdate` would return an incorrect YTD total if I were to select an invoice_num that occurred in, say, 2018. Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelCole . . . I'm a bit confused.  If you want this as of another date, then just use that date instead of `sysdate`.  Your sample data suggests that you want the most recent year/fiscal year.  You have a row with a date of Oct 2019 and it is not included in the results.